# Lots of warnings compiling Lua on Solaris SPARC?

Tags: c, gcc, lua, solaris

When I compile Lua (5.1.4) on Solaris SPARC I am getting the following warnings...and LOTS of them...

Below is just a snippet:

```
# /usr/ccs/bin/make solaris
cd src && /usr/ccs/bin/make solaris
/usr/ccs/bin/make all MYCFLAGS="-DLUA_USE_POSIX -DLUA_USE_DLOPEN" MYLIBS="-ldl"
/usr/sfw/bin/gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_POSIX -DLUA_USE_DLOPEN  -c  lapi.c
lapi.c: In function `luaA_pushobject':
lapi.c:92: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored
/usr/sfw/bin/gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_POSIX -DLUA_USE_DLOPEN  -c  lcode.c
lcode.c: In function `luaK_getlabel':
lcode.c:97: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored
lcode.c: In function `luaK_concat':
lcode.c:196: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored
lcode.c: In function `luaK_patchtohere':
lcode.c:182: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored
lcode.c: In function `luaK_patchlist':
lcode.c:176: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored
lcode.c: In function `luaK_checkstack':
lcode.c:206: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored
lcode.c: In function `luaK_reserveregs':
lcode.c:212: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored
lcode.c: In function `luaK_stringK':
```

Any idea what this could mean? Will it influence Lua on Solaris at all? Any changes I should make to the Makefile in /src folder?

Thanks for the help ;-)

Lynton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lua guesses that GCC's `visibility("hidden")` attribute is supported on any sufficiently recent GCC on any ELF platform.

But if the assembler being used by GCC does not support the directives for setting symbol visibility, GCC will issue this warning.  I think that's what's happening here.

Setting internal symbols as "hidden" allows more optimisation when building as a shared library, but is not actually necessary, so this should be harmless.

If they are bothering you, change the line in `src/luaconf.h` which reads

```
#define LUAI_FUNC       __attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) extern
```

to

```
#define LUAI_FUNC       extern
```